# Call from .cs (or .vb) into .aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Visual Studio solution, containing .cs and .vb projects, as well as .aspx files.  As usual, the .aspx files implement an ASP.NET site and make calls to the .cs and .vb projects.

Is it possible to do the reverse... i.e. make a call from a .cs or .vb file to a method in a .aspx file?  (Assume for the purpose of this question that there is a good reason for doing this)

Comment: Why would you want to put a method in an ASP page?  Unless you are talking about a javascript method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code driving your ASPX page is essentially just a class (be it from code-behind or on the aspx file itself), and as such can be instantiated/referenced by other classes which reference that assembly or project.  (As Matías pointed out, this may be an issue if you use a "Web Site" instead of a "Web Application" but I generally don't use the former so can't help you with that.)

One thing to keep in mind is the exact desired functionality of this function being called...

1. Is the method static or does it require a running instance of the class?
2. If it's an instance method, does it need to be called on the executing page or on any instance of the page?

That second one might get tricky.  If the current instance of the page needs to be referenced by the calling class, then that page will need to pass a reference to itself through the chain of method calls that leads to the class which calls the method on the page.  Sounds kind of ugly to me.

Can you describe in more detail what functionality you're attempting to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that code-behind Page class of your ASPX has public members like some method, why not? An ASP.NET application or precompiled web site compiles to a standard and regular .NET assembly.

Anyway, if it's a web site, it's a bad idea, because this is compiled into multiple assemblies and, if you don't use fixed assembly names, it'll be hard to catch that because names aren't predictable. But if you're talking about an ASP.NET application, no problem.

Comment: How can I make  a website use fixed assembly names?  Also, what if I don't want to put the public method in a code-behind... I want to embed it in the .aspx file

Comment: If it's second option, nevermind. You can't access these methods because ASPX pages are partial classes and the part that represents the code implemented in the view is compiled by the ASP.NET compiler when your website is running first time.

Comment: About fixed assembly names in ASP.NET websites, just read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992037.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds suspiciously like a web service. Websites can expose their underlying logic through web services that can be consumed in any .Net project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx